# Wrong Wolfram Mathematica code translation

Tags: c++, qt, wolfram-mathematica, linear-algebra

I am pretty new to *Mathematica*. I need to create 2d array dynamicly. I got some code in C++(Qt) and it looks like this:

```cpp
void Wave::getMatrix(int M, int N)
{
    int k = -N;
    while(k < N+1){
        QVector<tsk_type> temp_vec;

        for(int i = -N; i < N+1; i++){
            tsk_type temp_sum0;

            for(int ii = -M; ii < M+1; ii++ ){
                temp_sum0 += (getI(i-ii, b)/getY(ii)) * getJ(ii-k,b1,b2);
                        }
            temp_vec[temp_vec.size()-1] = temp_sum0;

            if (k == i)
                temp_vec[temp_vec.size()-1] -= l;

                }

        temp_vec.push_back(getD(S)*getI(S-k, b));
        main_array.push_back(temp_vec);
        k++;
    }

}
```

/
In *Mathematica*, I have already written all the functions that I need to make some linear equation system matrix which I can solve. So I use 'em to get 'list' of 'lists'.

When I run this code it's like executing something but outputs nothing. No even errors. 
Whats wrong? And how properly I should translate it? also, I assume that there are problem with 'List[]' and 'List[[]]' variables, so how shold I properly declare dynamic lists?

Here is the formula

[image]

Heres how I translated the code.

```
(*all globlas definiton is somewhere here*)

 k = -Nm;

        mainmatrix = List[[]];
        While[k < Nm + 1,
                    rowvalues = List[];
                    For[i = -Nm, i < Nm + 1, i++,

                           tempsum;



                           For[j = -M, j < M + 1, j++,    
                                      tempsum = tempsum +  (getI[i - j, a, b]/getGamma[j])                  * getJ[j - k, a1, b1, a2, b]
                           ]

                           AppendTo[rowvalues, tempsum];    

                           If[k == i, AppendTo[rowvalues, -l], 0]
                       ];


                       AppendTo[rowvalues, getD[S]*getI[S - k, a, b]];
                   AppendTo[mainmatrix, rowvalues];

         k++]
```

**UPD**:
all functions and data

```
Clear[k, a, b, a1, b1, a2, b2, angle, rho, omega, lambda, u];
(*constants*)  
rho = 1800; angle = 0.5; lambda = 3 * 10^9; omega = 1.5 * 10^6; u = 
 2*10^9;
BS = 1; DS = 1; T = 0.01; l = 0.01; S = 0;
a = 0.002; b = 0.008; a1 = 0.0; b1 = 0.002; a2 = 0.008; b2 = 1.0; M = 
7; Nm = 7;

getI[k_ , a_, b_] = Integrate[E^(I ((2 Pi)/l) k t), {t, a, b}]

getJ[k_ , a1_, b1_, a2_, b2_] = getI[k, a1, b1] + getI[k, a2, b2]

getL[n_] = angle + (2 Pi n/l); 

getK[j_] = If[j == 1, 
  answer = Sqrt[(rho*omega^2)/(lambda + 2*u)], 
  answer = Sqrt[(rho*omega^2)/(u)]
  ]; answer


getBeta[j_, n_] = If[(getL[n] > getK[j]), 
  beta = 0 + i*(getL[n]* getL[n]  * getK[j]*getK[j]),
  beta =  (getL[n]* getL[n]  * getK[j]*getK[j]) + i*0]; beta


getGamma[n_] = (((getL[n]*getL[n])/(getBeta[1, n])) + getBeta[2, n]);

getD[s_] = ((2 getL[s] * BS * getBeta[1, s] + DS) / (getL[s] * getL[s] 
            + getBeta[1, s]*getBeta[2, s] ));
```

Comment: It feels like this code is written by academic people rather than developers. Please fix the indent, and share all the necessary code that this code is using.

Comment: well, okay. but I don't really know how should look the WM code text ._. I mean the indents and stuff

Comment: the original c++ is a mess and does not correctly solve the given equation.  Do we want to translate the buuggy code or solve the equation?

Comment: @george it's not for solving it's for matrix creating

Comment: @george and the unknown values are the `C_i` values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if all this is exactly correct, but it is much closer.

```
In[1]:= n = 2; M = 2; (*dummy values for this example code*)
getGamma[i_] := RandomReal[]; (* dummy functions for this example code*)
getI[i_, a_, b_] := RandomReal[];
getJ[j_, a1_, b1_, a2_, b_] := RandomReal[];
getD[S_] := RandomReal[];

k = -n;(*N is a predefined Mathematica function and can't be a variable name*)
mainmatrix = List[];
While[k < n+1,
  rowvalues = List[];
  For[i = -n, i < n+1, i++,
   AppendTo[rowvalues, getGamma[i]];
   tempsum = 0; (*I think you wanted this initialized here*)
   For[j = -M, j < M+1, j++, 
    tempsum += getI[i-j, a, b]/getGamma[j]*getJ[j-k, a1, b1, a2, b]
   ];
   AppendTo[rowvalues, tempsum];
   If[k == i, AppendTo[rowvalues, -l]] (*no "else" needed if else does nothing*)
  ];
  AppendTo[rowvalues, getD[S]*getI[S-k, a, b]];
  AppendTo[mainmatrix, rowvalues];
  k++
];
mainmatrix (*display result*)

Out[8]= {{0.135926, 0.894736, -l, 0.699663, 1.91913, 0.702762, 
  28.4151, 0.730135, 19.6996, 0.583233, 21.2716, 0.398302},
{0.572982, 3.18868, 0.495877, 1.50816, -l, 0.686158,
  68.9278, 0.860748, 3.91516, 0.751198, 8.43028, 0.223722},
{0.931385, 3.16432, 0.931398, 5.10999, 0.241402, 4.54042,
  -l, 0.825971, 2.99634, 0.280342, 3.20253, 0.0731139},
{0.294396, 7.99678, 0.456691, 4.74995, 0.308643, 1.72647,
  0.883139, 5.64323, -l, 0.755833, 4.00285, 0.127718},
{0.790168, 0.751702, 0.744966, 2.40172, 0.537242, 3.08838,
  0.105972, 1.09212, 0.412047, 12.2475, -l, 0.397379}}
```

When time comes to use the matrix result realize that all Mathematica matrix and vector subscripts are 1..n, not 0..n-1 and not -n..n. So you will have to add an offset to any matrix subscripts when modifying code to use the resulting matrix.

You could, if it mattered to you, replace

```
tempsum = 0;(*I think you wanted this initialized here*)
For[j = -M, j < M + 1, j++, 
  tempsum += getI[i - j, a, b]/getGamma[j]*getJ[j - k, a1, b1, a2, b]];
AppendTo[rowvalues, tempsum];
```

with

```
AppendTo[rowvalues,Sum[getI[i-j,a,b]/getGamma[j]*getJ[j-k,a1,b1,a2,b],{j,-M,M}]];
```

That might have, for example, avoided the original bug of not initializing tempsum.

There are other bits of the code that could be rewritten to make use of Mathematica features, but you have to decide whether this would be good or bad to do.

Answer (score 1):

here you go without all the nasty use of `AppendTo`

```
 mainmatrix = Table[ 
               Insert[
                Append[
                 Flatten@Table[ {
                  getGamma[i],
                  Sum[getI[i - j, a, b]/getGamma[j]  getJ[j - k, a1, b1, a2, b],
                                  {j, -M, M}] },
                                    {i, -n, n}]  ,
                   getD[S]*getI[S - k, a, b]],
                          -l,2 (k + n + 1) + 1 ], 
                                        {k, -n, n}];
```

Edit:

on further study, it appears the C++ code actually throws away the  `getY(i)` value it pushes onto temp_vec, the result is even simpler:

```
 mainmatrix = Table[ 
       Append[
          Table[ Sum[getI[i - j, a, b]/
                getGamma[j]  getJ[j - k, a1, b1, a2, b]-l Boole[i == k],
                         {j, -M, M}] , {i, -n, n}]  ,
          getD[S]*getI[S - k, a, b]], {k, -n, n}];
```

yet another form, which actually begins to resemble your equation..

```
 lhs = Table[Sum[getI[i - j, a, b]/
    getGamma[j] getJ[j - k, a1, b1, a2, b], {j, -M, M}],
           {k, -n, n}, {i, -n, n}] - l IdentityMatrix[2 n + 1];
 rhs = Table[ getD[S]*getI[S - k, a, b] , {k, -n, n}];
 mainmatrix= Join[lhs, Transpose[{rhs}], 2]
```

Comment: Those arguments belong to `Insert`, which is doing the job of `If[k == i, AppendTo[rowvalues, -l]]` in @Bill 's answer.  That said I assumed Bills answer was correct since you accepted it, but the c++ version appears to be subtracting from the k=i component rather than appending.

Comment: oh, well. actually there are things a little bit different there. In WM it looks like  `If[k == i, 
 ReplacePart[rowvalues, Length[rowvalues] -> Last[rowvalues] - l]]`

Comment: How should I insert it there?

Comment: I see now I badly misunderstood parts of the original code. Can we simplify all this to just mainmatrix = Table[If[i<=n,
Sum[getI[i-j, a, b]/getGamma[j] getJ[j-k, a1, b1, a2, b], {j, -M, M}] - 1*Boole[k==i], getD[S]*getI[S-k, b]], {k, -n, n}, {i, -n, n+1}]. Is any chance of getting an example matrix from the original code so we can compare against this?

Comment: @Bill yeah, ofc sorry for not answering for two days ._.